# Firestore in Edge browser: not working or very slow

Tags: firebase, microsoft-edge, google-cloud-firestore

We're very close to putting our app into production, but when testing our site/app with (Microsoft) Edge it's very slow or even not working. 
We're using Angular 5 with these libraries:
  "firebase": "^4.11.0"
  "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6"
What could we do to make it work on Edge?

Comment: How did you isolate this to Firestore? Where's the code, data, and benchmarks to verify?

Comment: I'm using firestore with react and having the same issue in Edge. For me this happens only when user ia logged in. If user is not logged in, then it works fine